# Sorting Pandas DataFrame by coordinate proximity

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataset that contains multiple fields associated with a specific `x-y` coordinate.
The dataframe has the columns `df['x']` and `df['y']`, which represents the coordinate pairs for every row.
I wish to sort the dataframe by euclidean distance, so that I know that the neighboring rows are among the closest (I expect there to be multiple rows with the same distance to a given row).

How would I go about doing this?

**Clarification**
If the first row in the sorted dataframe is a random row from the original dataframe, the second row in the sorted array should be the element with the smallest euclidean distance to the first row, the third row should be the element with the smallest euclidean distance to the previous row etc.

**Extra context that may or may not be relevant**
The real issue I am trying to solve is that I have missing data.
My idea is to interpolate missing values in a given row from the neighbors, but this would require this sorting.
I am simply using the interpolate() function from Pandas for this purpose.

Comment: Euclidean distance from what?

Comment: I added a clarification in the question, but I am looking for the most efficient way for implementing the following procedure: 
1) Take a random element of the original dataframe. This will the first row in the sorted dataframe.
2) Find the row in the original dataframe with the smallest euclidean distance (computed from the x and y columns) and make it the second row in the sorted dataframe.

And so on. Hope that clarifies!

Comment: @FelixDarke if you found a way to do this, or a workaround for your whole problem, I'm very interested to know what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to each row which returns the distance, then sort by that distance. (There is a numpy function for euclidean distance which I am using in the example below)

```
df['dist'] = df[['x', 'y']].apply(lambda row: np.linalg.norm((row.x, row.y)), axis=1)
df.sort_values('dist', ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering!
However, this is not quite what I am thinking, maybe I did not phrase the question well enough.
For instance, consider the case when the points are spread along a circle. This code will simply sort by radius, not taking the relative distance between points into account.

Basically, I think I have to calculate the distance for every point, and sort the point based on that.

Answer (score 0):

let's say that you have a half circle like this:

```
line_cir = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
np.random.shuffle(line_cir)
cir_df = pd.DataFrame([line_cir, np.sqrt(1-line_cir**2)]).T
cir_df.plot.scatter(x=0, y=1, c=cir_df.index, cmap='viridis')
```

[unsorted half circle plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0fqL.png)

to sort the data frame according to the distances between the points you can choose a random point and iterate over the data to find the closest point, then do this again with the new point and so on until all the points are sorted.

this is not vary efficient but it works.

somthing like this:

```
# res remember the order of the rows.
# active is the current point - the first 
# is randomly choosing.
res = []
active = cir_df.iloc[0]
i = active.name
res.append(active)
cir_df.drop(i, inplace=True)

while not cir_df.empty:
    # score i is the distance between the active
    # point and the point in index i
    score = {}
    for i, row in cir_df.iterrows():
        score[np.linalg.norm(row - active)] = i
    best = min(score.keys())
    active = cir_df.loc[score[best]]
    res.append(active)
    cir_df.drop(score[best], inplace=True)
cir_df = pd.concat(res, axis=1).T
cir_df = cir_df.reset_index()
cir_df.plot.scatter(x=0, y=1, c=cir_df.index, cmap='viridis')
```

and here the sorted data:

[sorted half circle plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpLhA.png)

note that in the end of the plot the colour turns back to yellow, actually what happened is that the first point that was picked is about (0.9, 0.4), then the program sorted the data backward to the point (-1, 0) and then,  it turn back to the points between (0.9, 0.4) and (1, 0). simple modification to the code can overcome this problem, but for the question purpose this is sufficient.